# Let $f_n \to f$ in $L^1[0,1]$, prove $\int_{0}^{1}e^f\leq \liminf _{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}e^{f_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

[image]

I am a little clueless how to prove this. My observations:
We can use Jensen's inequality here $$e^{\int_{0}^{1}f}\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^f,e^{\int_{0}^{1}f_n}\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^{f_n} $$ However, I do not see his that helpful. I smell fatous but do not know how to apply it here. All I got from it is that

$$e^{\int_{0}^{1}\liminf f}\leq e^f$$

Comment: Do you know Fatou's Lemma? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma

Comment: @Conrad Yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By Markov's inequality, we have $f_n \to f$ in measure.
2. Since $t \mapsto e^t$ is a continuous function, it follows that $e^{f_n} \to e^f$ in measure (this is sometimes called the "continuous mapping theorem").
3. Apply Fatou's lemma.

Comment: In 2. we are using that we are on finite measure, correct?

Comment: @Sorfosh: Yes, that's correct.